# Left join with where clause in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do a left join with a where clause in linq.

I have leadsQuery table with 2500 rows. I want to join the LeadCons table into it. For a lead there can be multiple entries in the LeadCons table, hence I want to join only when the Status match. Else I want the fields to be NULL.

```
var data = from lead in leadsQuery
    join lcs in context.LeadCons on lead.ID equals lcs.LeadId into leadsWithCons
    from lcs in leadsWithCons.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where lead.Status == lcs.Status
    select new
    {
        LeadId = lead.ID,
        Source = lead.Source.ToString(),
    };
```

This query gives me ~1500 rows and leadsQuery has 2500. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing.   lead.Status == lcs.Status, so if Lcs.Status only has 1500 entries you will not get 2500.  You are joining on ID and if Status is not the same one both Lead and LeadsWithCons you will not get all 2500.

Comment: @jdweng doing `from lcs in leadsWithCons.DefaultIfEmpty()` should make a left join. Or?

Comment: Yes, left join will make the number of rows larger, but the filter lead.Status == lcs.Status make the number of rows smaller.  I'm just saying there is nothing unusual about getting only 1500 rows from your query when leadsQuery has 2500 rows.

Comment: @jdweng I do not want to filter the result. I want all 2500 rows with its corresponding LeadCons row. There can multiple LeadCons row for a lead Id and I want to choose the one where the Status matches else a null. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot have your cake and eat it too.  If your file has more than one type status you cannot filter for one status and then expect to get all the rows.  if you want all the rows your have to remove the WHERE. IF your IDs were 1,2,3 and the status A,B,C  You have 9 combinations. A1,A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1,C2,C3.  The leadsQuery and  leadsWithCons can match on one parameter A=A, B= B, C=C and then get all rows.  But what happens with A1 and A2?  They do not match so you loose rows.

Comment: That is why I want a left join, so I have nulls

Comment: Left join, so that elements on my left are constant

Comment: Suppose leadsQuery had A1 and B1.  Then LeadCons had B1 and C1.  The left outer join using ID = 1 would produce (A1,B1), (A1,C1), (B1,B1), (B1, C1)  Then filter on Status being equal you would get only (B1,B1).  LeadsQuery started with 2 rows but query resulted in one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late answer, hoping it is still helpful:

First, you aren't selecting any values from `LeadCons`, so what is the purpose of a join?
I shall assume maybe you want to extend your select, so let us say you want to select the property `foo`, so my next question: Why do you need a left join in your case? You can simply do a select:

```
var data = from lead in leadsQuery
    select new
    {
        Foo = context.LeadCons.Where(lcs => lead.Status == lcs.Status).SingleOrDefault().foo
        LeadId = lead.ID,
        Source = lead.Source.ToString(),
    };
```

This way you have the same number of items and for each item the desired `foo` value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just changing the your join to a join with multiple conditions, and then removing the where 'status equal status'

```
    from lead in leadsQuery
join lcs in context.LeadCons on new {
     p1 = lead.ID,
     p2 = lead.Status
}
equals
new {
     p1 = lcs.LeadId,
     p2 = lcs.Status
}
```

you can have a look at this nice article:
https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/linq-how-to-write-queries-with-complex-join-conditions/